# Issue with WebDriver test case

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have written a test case using WebDriver, I closed the browser in one method and again I am opening the browser not able to invoke

`driver.close();`i closed the browser through above command for again opening a browser i `driver.get(url)`
but i am getting error 
'Error communicating with the remote browser It may have died'

Comment: Please provide the code. This should work. unless you have called quit() on the driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to close the browser before navigating to the new URL, then do:

```
driver.quit();
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get(url);
```

However, why would you want to close the browser before navigating to the new URL in the first place?

**I can think of either one of two reasons:**

1. You want to go to the next URL with your browser's history cleaned.

   If this is indeed the case, then `deleteAllCookies` will do the job.
2. You cannot go to the next URL because some popup alert is preventing you doing it.

   If this is indeed the case, then neither `close` not `quit` will do the job.

Comment: What is OP's reason for closing the browser before navigating to the new URL? I can think of either one of two options: 1. Go to the next URL with cleaned history (for which, `deleteAllCookies` would do fine). 2. Some popup alert (for which, neither `close` not `quit` will help).

Answer (score 0):

Well you killed the browser with your `driver.close();`
In order to use the driver you must create a new one using something like `driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);`

Comment: "Close" only closes the current window does not close the driver.

Comment: @APaul Don't forget that if there is only one browser window open, `close()` tried to act like `quit()`. The semantics are slightly different, particularly for IE and Chrome, but go Firefox, they're much closer to the same thing. In any case, calling `close()` with only one browser window open will invalidate the session and force you to create a new browser instance.

Comment: +1 @JimEvans. I think most of the users are not working with multiple windows.

Answer (score 0):

Moving to answer from comment.

I think I got your issue. Though you have called the close() and it only should close the current window, you should use this if you want to shift between multiple windows.

For your case just don't close the driver it will use the same window to open the url.

Answer (score 0):

```
You have to use following way if you want to close the current browser and open 
a new one:    

webDriver.Close();
//Goto the Target website
WebDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("url");

And you can use following way if you want to close the browser and kill the
web driver:

webDriver.Close();
webDriver.Quit();
```